# Find all images in a Folder and replace them with a single image but keeping original file names

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-7-x64

Some thing slimier to this command:

Replace C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Folder1\image.jpg C:\Users\Jack\Folder2\ /s

I want to search for every .jpg file in folder 2, replace it with the image.jpg from folder 1, but keep the file name the same as it was in folder 2 originally.

Comment: Hint: looping `for /F "…" %G` against `dir /b /s "…\Folder2\*.jpg"`, start with `echo "%~G"`. See http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, run the following command from within the folder *C:\Users\Jack\Folder2\*:

```
for /F "delims=," %i in ('dir /b /s /x ".\*.jpg"') do copy /y C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Folder1\image.jpg "%i"
```